# ubercart checkout causes node to update

Tags: 6, nodes, ubercart

On a site I manage we have a view of recently updated products. The problem is that once a user purchases a product, that product is updated, which shoots it to the top of the list.

As far as I can tell there's no reason for a node update to be triggered simply because the product was purchased.

My first thought was the stock. However, uc_stock is directly calling db_query on uc_product_stock table and not touching node, or is it doing a node_load/node_save.

The closest I've found is that the update is triggering the nodeapi hook with the 'update' op. nodewords is picking it up as an update operation and I can see it in the dblog.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try newer versions of Nodewords. The code has been cleaned up further; it might help. Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the [Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps install and enable devel, and then look at the SQL queries to get the offending query which might give you clue about some other module that's doing an update.